# Modal not Closing in ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mdbootstrap

I am using  [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/basic/) for my project. I have check box on which i call ajax to perform some task and get response from php as 1 for success and 0 for failure. So I show modal before ajax call to show processing. modal displays but no closing in ajax response.

This is my modal code

```
  <div class="modal fade"  id="process" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data- 
  keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body text-center mb-1">

                  <p>Please Wait</p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
    </div>
</div>
 <script>
 status_val = 1;
 ac_no = 2;
 $('#process').modal();
  $.ajax({
      url:"reopen_account.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{'reopen':'reopen','status_val':status_val,'ac_no':ac_no},
      success:function(output)
        {
           if (output==1) 
           {
              $('#process').modal('hide');
           }
           else{
               $('#process').modal('hide')
                alert('Error occured');
              }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I've used .modal('hide'); its not working out for me.Where i am going wrong.

Comment: did you check your console ? is there any error ?

Comment: @Swati yes.there is no error.

Comment: you missed "  **;** "  after this --> $('#process').modal('hide')

Comment: did it but no luck @Swati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem occurs when you try to close your `modal` **immediately** after you've opened your modal and that's because the modal is not completely opened and modal status is still `close`.
So, In order to avoid to something like this happen again,you can set timeout to make sure your modal has completely opened!

```
$('#process').modal();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "reopen_account.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {'reopen': 'reopen', 'status_val': status_val, 'ac_no': ac_no},
                success: function (output) {
                    if (output != 1)
                        alert('Error occured');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#process').modal('hide');
                    }, 1000);
                },
            });
        });
```